# How to map with scala constructor

Tags: scala, functional-programming, type-mismatch

I'm working on the functional programming in Scala Coursera course; and I'm working on the exercise about Huffman coding trees.

Here's the code representing the Huffman tree

```
sealed abstract class CodeTree
case class Fork(left: CodeTree, right: CodeTree, chars: List[Char], weight: Int) extends CodeTree
case class Leaf(char: Char, weight: Int) extends CodeTree
```

And we're supposed it implement a function that takes a `List[(Char,Int)]` and returns a `List[Leaf]`

Here's my code:

```
def makeOrderedLeafList(freqs: List[(Char, Int)]): List[Leaf] = freqs.map(
    (c, i) => Leaf(c, i)
)
```

But I'm getting this error

[image]

Can anyone explain to me what's wrong with this code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the syntax you are looking for:

```
def makeOrderedLeafList(freqs: List[(Char, Int)]): List[Leaf] = freqs.map {
    case (c, i) => Leaf(c, i)
}
```

Since you are mapping a list of tuples, if you want to unpack them as you iterate you need to provide a matching tuple case.

You could also unpack your tuple like this:

```
def makeOrderedLeafList(freqs: List[(Char, Int)]): List[Leaf] = freqs.map(tuple => {
   val (c, i) = tuple
   Leaf(c, i)
})
```